# Why do I get "unable to generate the model" errors when adding tables in EF?

Tags: entity-framework

Working in a team environment, someone just created some tables I needed to add (EF Database First design).

I chose to "Update model from database...", selected the new tables, and got an obscure error message:

```
Unable to generate the model because of the following exception: 'The value for column 'DataType' in table 'TableDetails' is DBNull.
    Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.String'.
'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually caused by trying to add a table with **no primary key**. Just update the tables to have a primary key and you shouldn't get this error anymore.

It would be nice if the error made this clear. It would also be nice if everyone remembered to set primary keys on tables when they created them.

Hopefully this will save others the fruitless efforts I had of searching for an answer.